# How can I factory reset my device to bypass a new MDM solution?

Tags: samsung

I bought a Samsung Galaxy XCover Pro second-hand, approximately two months ago. It has worked fine and I have factory reset it previously which has also worked fine.

However, on factory resetting it and setting it up today, it told me suddenly that "This phone is controlled by [Company Name which I don't recognise] and needs to be enrolled using Knox Mobile Enrollment".

It has worked following factory resets fine before, which makes me wonder why this message has appeared on this particular occasion. Why might this be, and how can I seek to bypass it?

Comment: You have bought most likely a stolen device, therefore the correct way is to return the device and get your money back.

Comment: @Robert That was my first thought, but it seems to have worked fine for months, which I wouldn't have expected if that was the case.

Comment: That it worked fine just means that the thief managed to disable the MDM software somehow before selling it. Performing a factory reset also reset this "MDM bypass" and now you see the device as it is. The conclusion for people buying used Samsung devices is always to perform a factory reset first.

Comment: @Robert Per my question, I've factory reset it numerous times previously, so that would appear not to be the case.

Comment: How long do you own the device? May be the theft was not directly recognized and thus the MDM lock was activated some time after you had bought the device.

Comment: @Robert It's been two/three months now. I've also checked the IMEIs (dual SIM device) and neither are blacklisted, so I doubt that's the case.

Comment: Then the only way to get certainty in your case would be to contact that company and ask them to prove that your device belongs to them or otherwise how it can happen that their MDM is blocking your device.

Comment: @Robert I've emailed them and am waiting to hear back. I suspect that the device has been removed from their MDM, but the MDM solution is still installed on the device.